# Re-registering singleton bean on Spring

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking

I have a multi-module project where each module has its own unit tests and provides mocks for classes for that module.

I am trying to build an application context where each module could define its own mocks, but later unit tests would be able to override these mocks, for example:

```
public class Test {

    private static final class StupidMock {
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() {
        StaticApplicationContext applicationContext = new StaticApplicationContext();
        final ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = applicationContext.getBeanFactory();
        StupidMock stupidMock = new StupidMock();  // original mock
        beanFactory.registerSingleton(StupidMock.class.getName(), stupidMock);

        StupidMock f1 = applicationContext.getBean(StupidMock.class);
        if (f1 == null || f1 != stupidMock) {  // ensuring mock is retrievable
            fail("Could not get bean");
        }

        for (String names2Remove : beanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(StupidMock.class)) {
            applicationContext.removeBeanDefinition(names2Remove);  // <-- fails here 
        }

        StupidMock stupidMock2 = new StupidMock();     // replacement mock
        beanFactory.registerSingleton(StupidMock.class.getName(), stupidMock2);
    }
}
```

The problem is that this simple snippet fails on attempt to remove the first mock, claiming that there's no such bean (although Spring has just successfully provided me with a name).

If I just try to register another mock on top of the first one, Spring complains saying there is already object bound.

`DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry` has a `removeSingleton` method which is protected but I have no control over the bean factory owned by `StaticApplicationContext`. I could possibly use reflection and call this protected method anyway but it just feels wrong to do so for a such a simple task.

What am I doing wrong? How could I achieve singleton replacement on `StaticApplicationContext`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that registerSingleton method actually does not create a corresponding [BeanDefinition](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.html), it just registers the instantiated singleton associating it with the name that you have provided and retrieves it via the application Context later - there is no BeanDefinition underlying it though.

So when you call, `applicationContext.removeBeanDefinition(names2Remove);` it fails as there is no [bean definition](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.html), only the registered fully instantiated bean.

The fix is to not use registerSingleton, but instead to use a form of registerSingleton which uses a BeanDefinition:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("i", "10"); // set all the properties for the mock..
MutablePropertyValues propertyValues = new MutablePropertyValues(map);

beanFactory.registerSingleton(StupidMock.class.getName(), StupidMock.class, propertyValues);
```

Comment: I've solved this myself by providing my own Application Context class which is the same as StaticApplicationContext but allows to hook a custom BeanFactory (original StaticAppCtx doesn't allow this). The only difference for this custom BF is that it doesn't complain when singleton is re-registered. Thanks very much for your hint, I've learned quite a bit about Spring :)

Answer (score 2):

You can re-define a bean with [spring-reinject](https://github.com/sgri/spring-reinject).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring framework why dont you use [Spring testing framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/testing.html)

You can use the following annotations to have specific mocks on a per unit test basis

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```